# Using Delegates.observable with StateFlow in Kotlin(Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class which monitors the network state.
I'm using Flow to be able to collect the network state updates.
However, I also need to leave an option to use manual listeners that programmers can "hook" onto to be able to receive the network changes.

My code is simple :

```
 private val networkTypeState = MutableStateFlow<NetworkState>(NetworkState.Unknown)
 val networkTypeAsFlow: StateFlow<NetworkState> by notifyDelegate(networkTypeState)

 private fun <T> notifyDelegate(init: T) =
    Delegates.observable(init) { prop, _, new ->
        Lg.i("notify subscribers of network update: ${prop.name} = $new")
        notifySubscribers()
    }

sealed class NetworkState {
    object Unknown: NetworkState()
    object Disconnected: NetworkState()
    data class Connected(val isCellularOn: Boolean, val isWifiOn: Boolean): NetworkState()
}
```

Then when I update the state,
for example :

`networkTypeState.value = NetworkState.Disconnected` ,
the **`delegates.observable` does not get called**.

Worth noting, when I use `networkTypeAsFlow.collect { .. }` , this works well, meaning - the `networkTypeAsFlow` does get updated, it just doesn't call the `delegates.observable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Observable delegate monitors changes to the property itself. It is futile to use Observable for a `val` property, because a `val` property is never set to a new value. Mutating the object pointed at by the property is completely invisible to the property delegate.

If you want to observe changes, you can launch and collect:

```
private val networkTypeState = MutableStateFlow<NetworkState>(NetworkState.Unknown)
val networkTypeAsFlow: StateFlow<NetworkState> = networkTypeState

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        networkTypeAsFlow.collect { 
            Lg.i("notify subscribers of network update: $it")
            notifySubscribers()
        }
    }
}
```

An additional benefit here is that `notifySubscribers` will always be called from the same dispatcher, regardless of which thread the network state was changed from.

Comment: Oh I see.. Just a small question regarding the viewModelScope you have used here - I don't have a viewModel scope, since the Networking Monitoring class is a Singleton ("object") which many different components (not necessarily even ViewModels) are able to subscribe to. Would you in that case recommend to just override the CoroutineContext with a Job() and use it to launch the `collect` on networkTypeAsFlow ?

Comment: I think it should have a CoroutineScope that operates for its lifetime. Since it's a singleton, that would be forever, so you don't have to bother with cancelling it. GlobalScope could be used, but there are [potential drawbacks](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc), So I would instantiate one as a property of the singleton.